# How to pause and resume kubernetes pods with data?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have multiple micro services in my project. I want to dynamically pause and resume them without losing the data.

For example: I am deploying an theia ide and user created a folder. I want to down this service for sometime and resume again with the data.

References: 
https://github.com/theia-ide/theia

I have already tried with reducing replicas to 0 and 1. It removes the data. I want the data to be persistent.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: servicetest
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: servicetest
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: servicetest
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/YYYY-ZZZZ-249311/test
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: servicetest
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /data/
      volumes:
      - name: data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: service-pv-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: servicetest
  name: servicetest
spec:
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3000
  - name: deployport
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: servicetest
  type: LoadBalancer


kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: service-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

Comment: Add your pvc configuration.

Comment: thread updated...

Comment: what type of volume (emptyDir or hostPath) is being used on PersistentVolume.? Please share your PV details which are bound to above PVC.

Comment: @SubramanianManickam
it is an empty directory.
No worries, now i am using statefulset. Anyways thanks for the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether your underlying storage gets deleted depends on the persistent volume's [reclaim policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-pv-reclaim-policy/#why-change-reclaim-policy-of-a-persistentvolume). 
If you set the policy to `Retain`, it should keep your pod's PV around for later rather than deleting it's contents and purging the volume.

Also worth looking into [statefulset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#deployment-and-scaling-guarantees) if you're using this deployment of size 1, because deployments are "at least N" as opposed to statefulsets being "at most N" replicas. Statefulsets also let you have a different volume associated with each replica.

Comment: Statefulset is working like a charm in my case.
Thanks for the suggestion.